# Big Lebowski vs Barbie Girl question

Tags: reference, the-big-lebowski

My friend says that there is a common theme in *The Big Lebowski* (1998) and the music video for *Aqua - Barbie Girl* (1997).

Both scenes have a girl lying beside a pool in a lime green bathing suit with sunglasses, offering a lewd proposition. In barbie girl she says "I'll do whatever you want" and in Lebowski she sais "I will ... for a thousand dollars".

Is it a coincidence? Does The Big Lebowski reference Aqua's MTV video?

[image]
[image]

video version:

Comment: Barbie Girl was released May 1997, The Big Lebowski in January 1998. It's unlikely to be a direct reference. This was just a common trope.

Comment: It might not *reference* the 90s as much as it partially *defined* the 90s. Sort of like asking if Nirvana referenced the 90s.

Comment: @Toddwilcox Titanic and Jurassic park grossed 1-2 billion box office, and Lebowski 46 million... it's not even in the top 50 movies of the 90s... Narvana was the most famous group of the 90s... your comparison is mega inaccurate. MTV was playing barbie girl at the top 7 while Lebowski was shooting.

Comment: @orangedog, can you find another similar scene, if its a common trope? If not, your statement is unsubstantiated.

Comment: How many scenes are there where a girl is sitting making a "lewd proposition"? Probably thousands. She's often sitting by a pool. If she's sitting by a pool she is always wearing sunglasses and a bathing suit. "Lime green" is the only coincidence.

Comment: 1997 is well past the time when videos dominated programming on MTV, or when a video getting time on MTV could drive the popularity of a song. I'm sure this song was popular with some group of people, but it was absolutely unmemorable to me, and if I ever heard it in the 90's I have completely forgotten it.

Comment: @aliential End of the day, this question showed no research.  Your arguments are indefensible.

Comment: Jason, It's my girlfriends arguemets. if you walk back to your car and you see that  the battery is flat, your actions will have shown no research, and your position will be indefensible. besides, everything is relative, so those that communicate dogmatically are fools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Barbie Girl was released in [May 1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbie_Girl).

Principal photography on The Big Lebowski wrapped in [April 1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Lebowski#Principal_photography).

**So it's a coincidence.**

Comment: Cheers i was skeptical and she told me not to be so, so i had to ask from her viewpoint.